# Semantics of FOL, Question about a technicality

Tags: first-order-logic

In the semantics of predicate logic, the truth conditions for PL (predicate logic) sentences are defined, including quantified sentences. There, you always come across a cryptic condition, namely that $k$ is introduced as an arbitrary constant but must not occur in the formula $A(x)$. Then it is defined for instance:

$\forall x A(x)$ is true if $A(k)$ is true for every possible interpretation.

Why? Can you maybe show with a simple example?

Comment: This question, as it stands now, is hard to answer without more information about the specific definition you're referring to. I can guess what the arbitrary constant means and will attempt to answer the question, but the question should be self-contained.

Comment: Actually, no I can't. This could either be referring to the semantics of the existential quantifier (maybe) or maybe is justification of the inference rule existential instantiation (which does create fresh constant symbols), or perhaps something else. Neither of those things though is a perfect fit for your question, so it would really help if you added some more context.

Comment: Is this better/clearer?

Comment: Yes. I have one follow-up question though. Is $k$ intended to be a constant symbol or a free variable?

Comment: k is a constant symbol. Free variables usually denoted x,y right?

Comment: I don't know about *usually*. They're sometimes written that way. Do you have a link to the larger context where this is from, or, alternatively, the name of the textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely taken from a description of the semantics of first-order logic. This will usually include something like the following for describing the semantics of $\lor$.

$$ M, \vec{x} \models \varphi(\vec{x}) \lor \psi(\vec{x}) \;\;\text{if and only if $M, \vec{x} \models \varphi(\vec{x})$ or $M, \vec{x} \models \varphi(\vec{x})$} $$

This saying what it means for a formula to be true for a specific structure $M$ where the free variables get their values from $\vec{x}$.

Note that the two formulas on the right hand side of the biconditional $\varphi(\vec{x})$ and $\psi(\vec{x})$ are strict subformulas of $\varphi(\vec{x}) \lor \psi(\vec{x})$. Also, note that formulas are fundamentally finite, so if you keep recursing downwards to strict subformulas this process will eventually bottom out.

For the semantics of the universal quantifier, you have a choice in terms of how to define it, although both ways are equivalent.

$$ M, \vec{x} \models [\forall z](\varphi(z, \vec{x})) \;\;\text{if and only if for all $\vec{v}$ extending $\vec{x}$ with a value for $z$, it holds that $M, \vec{v} \models \varphi(\vec{v})$ } $$

Or perhaps

$$ M, \vec{x} \models [\forall z](\varphi(\vec{x})) \\ \textit{if and only if} \\ \text{for all $M^*$ extending $M$ with a value for $k$, it holds that $M^*, \vec{x} \models \varphi(k, \vec{x})$} $$

In both of these cases, we have to deal with a technical problem and that is *accidentally capturing a variable*.

Suppose we are using the second strategy for talking about the meaning of the universal quantifier.

If our language already has a constant symbol $0$ in it, for example, when we  consider the truth value of a well-formed formula headed by a universal quantifier, we **can't** replace the variable bound by that quantifier with $0$. It has to be a fresh symbol.

You get exactly the same problem in the other version, namely that when you get rid of a quantifier, you need to make sure that the bound variable is replaced with a fresh free variable.

---

As a quick example of why variable capture is a problem, consider the sentence $\varphi$ below. I'm using an existential quantifier here, but the same principle applies to universal quantifiers too.

$$ \varphi \;\;\text{is the sentence}\;\; [\exists a](a \neq k) $$

In prose, *there is an $a$ that is **not** equal to $k$*.

$\varphi$ is a sentence in the language $L_k = \{k\}$, with $k$ being a constant symbol. $k$ is not a free variable. It is the **structure's responsibility** to give $k$ a meaning.

So, let's suppose we have an $L_k$-structure $M$.

To be extra concrete, suppose the domain of $M$ is $\{0, 1\}$ and $k$ is interpreted as $0$.

Now, let's consider whether $M \models [\exists a](a \neq k)$ is true or not.

If we naively expand the recursive definition of $\models$, we get the following:

$$ M^* \models k \neq k \;\;\text{for some $M^*$ extending $M$} $$

Now, in any $L_k$ structure, $k \neq k$ is going to be false.

However, choosing $a$ to be $1$ would have made $a = k$ true in $M$, so something went wrong.

Basically, when we went to replace the bound variable $a$ with a constant symbol, we reused $k$ instead of introducing a fresh symbol.

Let's try it again with a fresh constant symbol $\ell$.

$$ M^* \models \ell \neq k \;\;\text{for some $M^*$ extending $M$} $$

This is true. We can send $\ell$ to $1$.

Comment: Thx. Can you give also a baby example, so that one can „see“ the problem?